# In C# How to get data from a Dataview with two columns to a DataTable with one column

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, dataview

I had a Dataview with two columns of data. Now I defined a Datatable with one column which is intended to get only first column data from the Dataview object

```
 DataTable dtResult = new DataTable("dtResult");
 DataColumn colCompanyID = dtResult.Columns.Add("CompanyID",typeof(Int32));
```

When I tried to do the below....my Datatable object is getting ovveride with the dataview data. My intention is to preserve the one column structure of my Datatable and need only one column data from DataView.

```
dtResult = dvCompany.ToTable(); 
// Here Datatable structure is not preserved which is getting ovveride Dataview (CompanyID, Name).
```

How can I solve this problem ???

Comment: you need to look up how to use the `Copy` method in regards to the DataTable [MSDN DataTable.Copy Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or look at how to use the `Merge` function...

Comment: it works with Datatable only. But in my requirement it is Dataview

Comment: you can do the same thing with a DataTable and binding the table to the Datagridview.. so why can't you create a query to pull back what you need vs this approach.. ...how are you getting the data..can you show the query(s)